# deleting lines in Jupyter file with linux command line

Tags: linux, text, sed, jupyter

I have a notebook file which include millions of lines as following and because of those lines ( printing yes or no for debug reason), chrome is not able to lunch my code any more.

```
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "no\n",
  "yes\n",
  "no\n",
```

I want to delete those, used sed and managed to delete  ($ sed '/no/d' debugger.ipynb  > new2.ipynb$,  $ sed '/yes/d' new2.ipynb  > new3.ipynb $ )

but I am not able to lunch the resulting file, 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4FLh.png)

I guess I have deleted some structure as well. 
Is there a better way to do?

Comment: Only match `"no\n",` and leave other lines also containing `no` alone, i.e. `sed /'^"no\\n",$'/d` - ^/$ meaning start/end of line.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -v -e '^  "no\\n",$' -e '^  "yes\\n",$' debugger.ipyndb > new3.ipyndb`

Using the `-v` option, this gives you the lines *not* matching `"no\n",` and `"yes\n",`.

You could also consider using the `-x` exact line and `-F` fixed strings options to speed grep up (-F might require removing the regex `^` and `$` syntax for line start/end.)  But if it's only millions of lines, and only needs to run once, I doubt it's worth playing with those options.